# Error when running 'npm start': 'ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am attempting to open a react app with the npm start command, and am getting the following output:

```
(node:5199) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

> react-bootstrap-components@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

/Users/username/Desktop/app folder name/node-postgres/react-app/node_modules/queue-microtask/index.js:5
  ? queueMicrotask.bind(globalThis)
                        ^

ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Desktop/app folder name/node-postgres/react-app/node_modules/queue-microtask/index.js:5:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Desktop/app folder name/node-postgres/react-app/node_modules/run-parallel/index.js:4:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
```

I unfortunately cannot share the app code for error replication purposes, but am wondering if a  solution can be proposed based on this output alone. I have already tried updating npm with `npm install -g npm@latest`, which removed some previous errors, but not this one.

Comment: What version of node are you running? (`globalThis` is unrelated to npm)

Comment: Updated to the latest version and it was resolved. Thanks!

Comment: I thought as much. `globalThis` was introduced in node v12